# Excel: Assign equally numbers in a columns to n Groups excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split

Giving a range of numbers, i need to assign the numbers in the range equally to n groups, with an Excel formula (or macro, but formula is better).
Ex: The sum of Price Column is 10, so giving 2 groups, both should have a total price of 5.
Ex 2: With a total price of 15, and 3 groups, every group should have a total price of 5, etc.

| Price | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=MATCH(SCAN(0,A2:A5,SUM),SEQUENCE(2,,,SUM(A2:A5)/2))
```

Or, if you don't have access to the condensed form of `LAMBDA()` helpers yet:

```
=MATCH(SCAN(0,A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)),SEQUENCE(2,,,SUM(A2:A5)/2))
```

**Note**: You should read `SEQUENCE(2,,,SUM(A2:A5)/2)` as `SEQUENCE(n,,,SUM(A2:A5)/n)`.

Comment: Very clever solution

Comment: The First solution returns erorr, probably beacause the condensed form of LAMBDA() it's not available.
The Second solution works for the given set of data of the example, but not for a more complex set of data: 

B2 =MATCH(SCAN(0;A2:A22;LAMBDA(x;y;x+y));SEQUENCE(2;;;SUM(A2:A22)/2))

https://ibb.co/t4Wz6FY

Group 1 Price Total Formula = 98 Expected 149
Group 2 Price Total Formula = 200 Expected 149

The Price Total it's not it is not necessarily divisible by n, so the expected it could be for example also 148 - 150

I'm sorry maybe my question was not posted clearly.